Can I use =isnumber(search( function on multiple columns at the same time?
I have a table where I have to check row by row that the org name, work country and location refer to the same country.
In the below table there are a few examples where the last 3 rows are incorrect, the first 6 are correct.
Sheet and table name: Master
columns: | E (5)| ... | AV (48) | AW (49) |



Organization Name
F - AU
Work Country
Work Location




4605 IS AT CORE
...
Austria
Vienna At Loc 2


8000 RS SALES
...
Serbia
Belgrade Cs Loc


5550 CP GM PROD
...
United Kingdom
London Uk Loc


5000 ES GB PROD
...
United Kingdom
Oxford Gb Loc 2


4600 ES ES CORE ABC
...
Spain
Barcelona Es Loc 2


1000 CP ES CORE ABC
...
Spain
Barcelona Es Loc 2


7420 CP BE PROD
...
Belgium
Vienna At Loc


4600 IS ES CORE ABC
...
Austria
Barcelona Es Loc 2


7420 ES ES PROD
...
Belgium
Brussels Be Loc




There are a couple of things to bear in mind:

The main principle is that I check the country with the corresponding country code(s): Austria - At, France - Fr, etc.
If the work location is Expatriate, the row is correct
The three columns are not next to each other in the table I'm checking and they are on a sheet called 'MASTER'
The formula for the checking is on a different sheet called 'Mismatch Finder')
CP, IS and ES refer to sectors and ES can cause issues when searching for Spain as the country code for them are ES as well; therefore I was looking for "CP ES" and "S ES" in my formula.
Some countries have multiple possibilities:




Country
Work Location code
Organization Name Code




Serbia
cs
rs


Spain
es
cp es, s es


United Kingdom
gb, uk
gm, gb




To check for each country, I have created the below formula; however, since this goes for 60 countries I ran out of character before I could finish.
=IF(OR(
 AND(
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" at ",Table2[@[Work Location]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Austria",Table2[@[Work Country]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" at ",Table2[@[Organization Name]]))),
 AND(
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" be ",Table2[@[Work Location]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Belgium",Table2[@[Work Country]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" be ",Table2[@[Organization Name]]))),
 AND(
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" es ",Table2[@[Work Location]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Spain",Table2[@[Work Country]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cp es",Table2[@[Organization Name]]))),
 AND(
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" es ",Table2[@[Work Location]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Spain",Table2[@[Work Country]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("s es",Table2[@[Organization Name]]))),
 AND(
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" cs ",Table2[@[Work Location]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Serbia",Table2[@[Work Country]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" rs ",Table2[@[Organization Name]]))),
 AND(
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" uk ",Table2[@[Work Location]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("United Kingdom",Table2[@[Work Country]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" gm ",Table2[@[Organization Name]]))),
 AND(
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" gb ",Table2[@[Work Location]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("United Kingdom",Table2[@[Work Country]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" gm ",Table2[@[Organization Name]]))),
 AND(
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" uk ",Table2[@[Work Location]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("United Kingdom",Table2[@[Work Country]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" gb ",Table2[@[Organization Name]]))),
 AND(
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" gb ",Table2[@[Work Location]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("United Kingdom",Table2[@[Work Country]])),
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" gb ",Table2[@[Organization Name]]))),
 ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Expatriate",Master[@[Work Location]])))),
     "correct","incorrect")

Some of you suggested solutions but I couldn't implement it so far because I did not give enough information up until now, for which I apologize.
Also, I never used advanced functions like Lambda, and cannot modify the formula until I understand it better.

I tired using the tool but it just does not look right

This one you mean? Yeah, I switched rs and cs up by accident. Sorry, ppl make mistakes sometimes.

Here is one way of doing this, also this assumes there is no Excel Constraints as per the tags posted, then the following formula should work:


• Formula used in cell E2
=LET(
     Σ,{"Austria","at";"Belgium","be";"Spain","es"},
     BYROW(WorkTbl, LAMBDA(α,
     IF(AND(1-ISERR(SEARCH(" "&VLOOKUP(INDEX(α,,2),Σ,2,0)&" "," "&CHOOSECOLS(α,1,3)&" "))),
     "Correct","Incorrect"))))


Basically, this Σ refers to a Table constructed for the search key, instead of embedding it within a formula, the below uses ETA LAMBDA():


=IF(BYROW(IFERROR(SEARCH(" "&VLOOKUP(WorkTbl[Work Country],SearchTbl,2,0)&" ",CHOOSECOLS(WorkTbl,1,3)),0),AND),"Correct","Incorrect")


As per OP's Comments:

I cannot say that I understand the formula but it works and I am very
greatful for it. However, there are a few countries where there are
different country codes used and I don"t know how I could do the
search based on 3 terms and not just 2. For example Serbia has "RS" in
work location and "CS" in org name. Is there a way to modify the
formula to check 3 conditions where necessary?


• Updated Formula:
=LET(
     Σ,SearchTbl,
     BYROW(WorkTbl, LAMBDA(α,
     LET(δ, VLOOKUP(INDEX(α,,2),Σ,{2,3},0),
     φ, IF(δ=0,TAKE(δ,,1),δ),
     IF(AND(1-ISERR(SEARCH(" "&φ&" "," "&CHOOSECOLS(α,1,3)&" "))),
     "Correct","Incorrect")))))




Test Cases:






Helper function _match is used to split codes for location and org name and match.

Since the country name should match, use it at a basis to look up codes for location and org (codes_row).

Valid is the lookup table (in 'Mismatch Finder')


=LET(
    _match, LAMBDA(in_text, codes,
        LET(
            codes, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(codes, ",")),
            OR(
                MAP(
                    codes,
                    LAMBDA(code,
                        ISNUMBER(SEARCH(code, in_text))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    codes_row, XMATCH([@[Work Country]], Valid[Country]),
    IFS(
        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Expatriate", [@[Work Location]])),
        "correct",
        NOT(ISNUMBER(codes_row)),
        "incorrect",
        AND(
            _match(
                [@[Work Location]],
                INDEX(Valid[Work Location code], codes_row, )
            ),
            _match(
                [@[Organization Name]],
                INDEX(
                    Valid[Organization Name Code],
                    codes_row,
                    
                )
            )
        ),
        "correct",
        TRUE,
        "incorrect"
    )
)



Sorry, I wasn't clear in my problem statement. I have to check row by row that each of the three fields refer to the same country.
For example, if the work location has 'AT' then the org name has to have 'AT' as well, and the country has to be Austria. In your table, the second line should be also incorrect, since the country is Poland but the other two fields refer to a different country, Austria.

Thanks for clarifying and I have a better understanding of the issue now. Let me take a look :)

Please take a look the alternate solution with specifying comma separated codes.

Apologies for the late reply, I have carefully updated my post to reflect all the nuances I have to check for. To be completely honest I don't really understand the code you suggested but I would really like to as I need to figure this out. What do _codes_found_at_start, _country_index, and the others mean? Should I replace them with something?

Not sure whether you're still working on this. Please see the updated answer and let me know whether it helps or it needs more explanation.

Do I understand correctly that _match, in_text, code, codes, codes_row are named ranges? And Valid is the name of the table on the right? Do I have to add a function to the named range? Sorry, I never used Lambda or named ranges before.

I'm sorry - those are locally declared variables and function used within the LET and, you're right, Valid is the name of the table on right. Please take a look at LET function - Microsoft Support when you get chance.
